# How to trigger server-side event from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I trigger a server control event from a client-side JavaScript?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call a server side method on a client side event you need to do the following:

1- Create the server side method:

```
void DoSomething(...) { ... }
```

2- Implement the `System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent` which take one string argument (You can assign the name to the value of this argument).:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) 
{
        DoSomething(...);
}
```

3- Write a script to trigger post back:

```
function TriggerPostBack(control, arg){
    __doPostBack(control, arg);
}
```

4- Call the PostBack trigger function when needed:

```
<a .... onclick="TriggerPostBack('control', 'arg')" .. />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way too:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('<%=ServerControl.ClientID%>').Event(); 
    return false;">OK</a>
```

Comment: this is such an ugly hack ;) where do you leave the button? Your other answer is much better.